# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException - junit eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, junit, jar

When doing junit test for my spring project in eclipse Im getting a failure as,

> Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have already added the **jar file to libraries** and set the **environment variables path**. But still it gives the error.

The tested function is as below.

```
@Test
void testSave() {
    dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contactdb");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");

    dao = new ContactDAOImpl(dataSource);

    Contact contact = new Contact("Steve Jobs", "steve@apple.com", "California, USA", "0325698745");
    int result = dao.save(contact);

    assertTrue(result > 0);
}
```

My **pom.xml** file is also attached.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.codejava.contact</groupId>
  <artifactId>ContactManager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>13</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>5.9.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It looks like the connection to the database was successful except the username and password are wrong. Are you sure root/root is correct for that DB?

Comment: @Joni yes I check it twise. Password is also root.

Comment: If user and and password are correct, then root is not allowed to log in through localhost:3306. Can you include the output from `select * from mysql.user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the following line to load the driver.

```
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager) for more information.

Apart from this, reset your database `root` password and try again.

Comment: After the change it says, ->> Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Comment: @ShaviPathirana - In fact, you do not need to set the database driver class name. It is automatically loaded when `DriverManager.getConnection...` is called. I've updated my answer accordingly.